# How to connect to MongoDB Enabled with SSL and Auth using java

Tags: java, mongodb, ssl-certificate, mongodb-java-3.8

**QUESTION**:

I have CA Certificate as **cafile.pem**, PEM Certificate as **mongodb.pem**. I am not sure how to use it in java to authentication and connect MongoDB. Any suggestion would be deeply appreciate. Let me know if you want more information to put up.

**Scenario:**

I am using **mongo-java-driver-3.4.3.jar** to connect to an *SSL enabled, Authentication enabled* **MongoDB 3.7.9** sharded cluster with 3 instances. Below is the java code I am trying to connect to this server.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.bson.Document;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ReadPreference;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

public class Starter {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        List<MongoCredential> mongoCredentials = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();
        mongoCredentials.add(MongoCredential.
        createScramSha1Credential("admin", "admin", "admin".toCharArray()));

        List<ServerAddress> serverAddressArray = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();

        serverAddressArray.add(new ServerAddress("xyz.domain.com", 27017));

        MongoClientOptions options = new MongoClientOptions.Builder()
                                        .sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(false)
                                        .sslEnabled(true)
                                        .readPreference(ReadPreference.primaryPreferred())
                                        .build();
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(serverAddressArray, mongoCredentials, options);
        try {
            System.out.println("----- Step 1 ------");
            MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("CIM");
            System.out.println("----- Step 2 ------");
            MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("orders");
            System.out.println("No of Documents in orders collection: " + collection.count());
          } catch (Exception ex) {
              System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
          }
    }       
}
```

I get below error;

```
----- Step 1 ------
----- Step 2 ------
Sep 20, 2018 2:48:02 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=ReadPreference{name=primaryPreferred}} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=torvm-core16.sigma-systems.com:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
Sep 20, 2018 2:48:03 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server xyz.domain.com:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:88)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:494)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:224)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveReply(CommandHelper.java:134)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:121)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
    .............
```

Anyways I am able to connect MongoServer as below configuration in RoboMongo3T.

[image]

**mongodb.pem**

```
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: AA 4A 8D C5 AC CE 7A 08 F6 F1 00 2C 78 20 8D 0C 51 DE 66 F5 
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.xyz.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFPzCCBCegAwIBAgIJAKpTjrMr7rpZMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIG0MQswCQYD
.
.
.
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes: <No Attributes>
subject=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
issuer=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFPzCCBCegAwIBAgIJAKpTjrMr7rpZMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIG0MQswCQYD
.
.
.
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: AA 4A 8D C5 AC CE 7A 08 F6 F1 00 2C 78 20 8D 0C 51 DE 66 F5 
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIFPzCCBCegAwIBAgIJAKpTjrMr7rpZMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIG0MQswCQYD
.
.
.
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**cafile.pem**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEADCCAuigAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBjMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEh
.
.
.
.
.

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I first created a **mongodb.pkcs12** file using command `openssl pkcs12 -export -out mongodb.pkcs12 -in mongodb.pem`.
2. I had to include this file in the file path for **keyStore** and **trustStore** in below code (**NOTE**: My code has also changed and minimized).

   ```
   import org.bson.Document;

   import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
   import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
   import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
   import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

   public class Starter {

       private static MongoClient mongoClient;

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "mongodb.pkcs12");
           System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "yourPassword");
           System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "mongodb.pkcs12");
           System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "yourPassword");

           MongoClientURI mongoClientURI = new MongoClientURI(
                   "mongodb://admin:admin@hostname3.xyz.com,hostname2.xyz.com:27017,hostname3.xyz.com:27017/admin?ssl=true");
           mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoClientURI);

           try {
               MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("CIM");
               MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("orders");
               System.out.println("No of Documents in orders collection: "
                       + collection.count());
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Above code is working very well and below is the output I got,

```
    Sep 24, 2018 3:49:13 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
    INFO: Discovered cluster type of SHARDED
    Sep 24, 2018 3:49:15 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
    INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:4}] to hostname3.xyz.com:27017
    No of Documents in orders collection: 3
```

Comment: I have the same problem except that I dont have a ".pem" file but a ".crt" file, and want to access my db with tls. Do you know how to proceed? Or how to create the keystore without the pem file?